# Como instalo pygame para python 3.7.0 de 32 bits?

Tags: python, pip

Intente instalarla todo el dia con la la herramiento "pip" pero siempre aparece este mensaje y el paquete nunca llega a instalarse.
[image: Perdonen la fea calidad, no aceptaba un archivo que pesara mas, en fin, ese es el error que aparece en la terminal]

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega el texto del error como texto

Comment: Como comenta αλρθα es mas fácil para todos si copias y pegas la excepción completa del error. En cuanto al error ¿puedes instalar otras librerías con pip? Si no te deja instalar nada y no tienes problemas de conexión, lo primero que tienes que descartar dado el error es que el **firewall no esté bloqueando el acceso a los servidores de  PyPi por parte de pip**.  Mira lo del firewall (el de Windows o un tercero que puedas tener) y si lo bloquea crea una nueva regla para permitir la conexión de pip. Si descartas lo del firewall comenta y buscamos otras causas.

Comment: Siempre puedes descargarte los whl de Pygame y sus dependencias desde [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/) e instalarlos usando `pip nombre_del_archivo.whl`, pero es más fácil dejar que pip resuelva y descargue las dependencias automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyGame no está, a día de hoy, completamente portado a Python 3, de modo que no existe un paquete para preinstalar, a diferencia de su versión para Python 2.

[Aquí te dejo el enlace a la documentación oficial](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)

Para instalarlo como es debido en python3 sigue los siguientes pasos:

**Instalación de la librería SDL:**

```
$ sudo aptitude install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-console 
libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-sound1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev 
libsdl-net1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libavformat-dev 
libswscale-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

Una vez instalados los archivos con los encabezados, es preciso recuperar el código fuente de PyGame de la siguiente manera (**una vez nos hemos ubicado en la carpeta de destino**):

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame  
$ cd pygame  
$ python3 config.py
```

Una vez hecho esto veras los requisitos previos y su estado. **Si alguno de los requisitos previos no estuviera cubierto, será preciso resolverlo antes de pasar a la siguiente etapa**:

```
$ python3 setup.py
```

Espero que con esto puedas instalar `pygame` en python 3 como es debido. Suerte!!

**Fuente:** Python 3 - Los fundamentos del lenguaje -- Ediciones ENI.

**EDITO**

Esta respuesta está basada en un libro sobre los fundamentos del lenguaje python en el que se tocan entre otras librerías pygame, pero buceando un poco por la documentación he visto que tiene su preinstalación a través de pip. Debe ser que ya lo han portado a python 3.

**Instalación a través de pip:**

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

El flag `--user` es para que la instalación la haga en el directorio del usuario y no directorio principal.

[Esta es la guía de instalación de la documentación oficial](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation), incluye instalaciones para sistemas `Linux`, `Windows` y `Mac`.

Suerte!